# Register multiple service instances into gRPC server and associate a different port number to each service instance?

Tags: grpc, grpc-c++

I could register multiple service instances (from the same service class) to `grpc::Server` via `grpc::ServerBuilder::RegisterService(service_instance)`,  but could I associate each service instance to a different network port?

The intention is servicing a client on a different port via a dedicated service instance.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot create multiple servers, for each service and port?

Comment: @menghanl is there any load balance which is only done in one `grpc::Server`? If so, I'd like to share such resources in one `grpc::Server` instead of creating multiple.